# Выделить слова между двумя скобками

Tags: javascript, выделение-текста

У меня  есть проблема. Хочу сделать ***API*** на JS. Вот как это выглядит.

Пользователь вводит запрос который должен применяться :

```
var req = "msg:{name}:{message}" // Пример запроса: "msg:john:Hello, John"
```

*Пользователь может может ввести и больше принимаемых параметров.*
Вся суть в том что нужно сначала узнать что за ключи у параметров и потом запросе узнать значение.

И мне нужно что бы на выходе было что то такое :

```
{
  name: "John",
  msg: "Hello, John"
}
```

Comment: Прости немного не правильно написал не msg, а message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вариант с функцией `split`:

```js
var req = "msg:john:Hello, John";
var spl = req.split(':');

var data = {
  name: spl[1], 
  message: spl[2]
};

console.log(data);
```

Вариант с регулярным выражением:

```js
var req = "msg:john:Hello, John";
var found = req.match(/msg:(.+):(.+)/);

var data = {
  name: found[1],
  message: found[2]
};

console.log(data);
```